# Link tag printing rather than being interpreted

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to include a css file in a layout file on a rails site and my  tag contained in the header is not being interpreted, it is instead displaying on the page.  I put the tag in the  section.  The link tag is shown below.  I assign page_style and it is correctly inserted on the page but the page displays the second tag below instead of interpreting the tag.

```
<%= "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/stylesheets/#{@page_style}.css\">"    if !@page_style.nil? %>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/standard.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails (3 and up), strings are HTML-escaped before being shown, so your `<` are being encoded as `&lt;`, etc.

You can add `.html_safe` to your string like this:

```
<%= "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/stylesheets/#{@page_style}.css\">".html_safe if !@page_style.nil? %>
```

However, it would be a bit more Rails-y if you rewrote it to use the `stylesheet_link_tag` helper like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag(@page_style) if @page_style.present? %>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I went with the more rails-y approach and it is working

Answer (score 0):

I don#t really see where you started the Rails-command.
Usually basic Rails starts the following:

```
<% if @page_style.nil? %>
    // Do something here
<% end %>
```

You may want to add 'binding.pry' within your controller right after @page_style was used. Within your server-tab it then should open up your rails console where you can check the output of @page_style (and even apply the @page_style.nil? operation and check its outcome).